# Merging two Timezone aware date objects in javascript- one for date, the other for time

Tags: javascript, datetime, merge

Lets say I have the following timezone aware `Date` objects in Javascript:

```
var date1 = new Date("2019-07-02T07:30:00-05:00");
var date2 = new Date("2020-08-05T00:00:00-05:00");
```

What is the best way to merge these two, such that I keep the time from `date1` and the date from `date2`, yielding:

```
new Date("2020-08-05T07:30:00-05:00");
```

I've tried:

```
date1.setDate(date2.getDate());
date1.setMonth(date2.getMonth());
date1.setYear(date2.getYear());
```

which set the day and month correctly for `date1`, but the year is incorrectly set to "120" with the example inputs above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- `Date` objects cannot be time zone aware.  When passed a string with a time zone offset like the ones you showed here, they use that offset to determine the equivalent UTC time.  Ultimately the only thing stored within the `Date` object is the numeric Unix timestamp that corresponds to that UTC time.  You can see this with `.getTime()` or `.valueOf()`.
- `getDay`/`setDay` are for the day of the week, Saturday (0) through Sunday (6).  Use `getDate`/`setDate` for the day of the month.
- `getYear`/`setYear` are for two-digit years (or rather the current year minus 1900), and should not be used ever.  Use `getFullYear`/`SetFullYear` instead.

Because of the first point, what you ask is not possible.  Or at least, not possible with the full range of values that might be encountered in such strings.  Instead, you can manipulate the strings directly, or you can use a library such as [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) or [Moment](https://momentjs.com/).

I'd also think a bit harder about what you're actually trying to accomplish.  Where do these two values come from? Why are portions of the data important and others to be discarded?  What will you do if the offsets are different between the two values?  Only you can answer these points.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll correct the code above- I am actually already using `setDate`/`getDate`, and it was a typo in the question.  The key is the `getYear` vs. `getFullYear`.  That fixed the issue!

Comment: Great points in your last paragraph.  What I am trying to accomplish is using a separate date-picker component, and time-picker component for data entry.  The data returned from the date-picker component destroys the attached time (I suppose it is in constructing the calander picker), so the Date that comes back is a date, with the same timezone as the input, with a new month/day/year and the time set to 00:00:00.  So I needed to take that and combine it with the original datetime (which will always have the same timezone set).  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That makes sense indeed, but I can see there could be some edge cases on days with time zone transitions (start of DST, end of DST, or change in standard time) with separate pickers.  Maybe not critical for your case, but something to be aware of.  Note that many of the better pickers out there return raw strings instead of `Date` objects, to avoid such concerns.  Also the built-in HTML5 `<input type="date"/>` and `<input type="time"/>` do that as well.

Comment: Ugh.. Cant we just get rid of DST already? ;)  In all seriousness, thank you for answering my question, and for the additional food for thought.  I'll need to look a bit closer at how I am doing things, to make sure I'm not making a mess for myself.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate the ISO strings directly:

```js
const date1 = new Date("2019-07-02T07:30:00-05:00");
const date2 = new Date("2020-08-05T00:00:00-05:00");

const date3 = new Date([
  date2.toISOString().split('T')[0],
  'T',
  date1.toISOString().split('T')[1],
].join(''));

console.log({date1, date2, date3});
```

By the way, there is no "timezone-aware" date objects. Once `Date(...)` is fired, time is UTC. [`getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) gets the difference from the local timezone to UTC.

Comment: Understood (re: 'timezone aware').  One issue I have- those ISO Strings don't actually exist (the dates were passed as date objects from another function, I just used ISO strings here as an example).  So I suppose for your solution, I'd need to convert the dates to strings, manipulate them, then pass them back into a `Date` object.

Comment: @MarkD Yeah it's already done in the snippet above with `Date.toISOString()`. It doesn't destruct the original date object so you don't need to *"pass them back into a Date object"*.